# How to write dynamic internal css with escaped characters for razor?

Tags: css, razor, escaping

I am trying to add dynamic internal css in razor. I CANNOT use external files. I want to add some css in the head element of my cshtml file.

For example: I want to add some background images to some elements.
I am adding this simplified code of what I have tried. In the real case the List classes and urls would be dynamic.

```
@string.Join("\n\n", new List<string> { ".someClass{background: url('urlToMyImage')}" })
```

The problem with this approach is that I am having problems escaping the characters `'` and `\n`. and I am getting `.someClass{background: url(&#x27;urlToMyImage&#x27;)}`

I also tried using `@Html.Raw` but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were thinking along the right lines with `@Html.Raw`.  I'm not sure how you implemented it, but this will work:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Join("\n\n", new List<string> { ".someClass{background: url('urlToMyImage')}" }))
```

As will the somewhat longer:

```
@{
     string output;

     output = string.Join("\n\n", new List<string> { ".someClass{background: url('urlToMyImage')}" });
     @Html.Raw(output);
 }
```